# Iteração lenta com pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iterator

Estou usando o seguinte código para gerar todos os acordes de até 6 elementos, com 12 notas possíveis para cada elemento. Então a quantidade de acordes gerados deve ser : `(12*12*12*12*12*12) + (12*12*12*12*12) + (12*12*12*12) + (12*12*12) + (12*12) + (12) = 3.257.436` . Certo ?

Bom, segundo meus calculos levará cerca de 30 horas para terminar no meu notebook. Isso se a velocidade de processamento não mudar conforme o tempo ... Criei uma virtual machine  gratuita no google clouds, e deixei esse código rodando lá tbm (8 vCpus, 8gb de ram) mas já fazem algumas horas.

Então estou pensando se não há uma forma de acelerar o processo. Não consegui usar as Vm com 16 vCpus. E não sei o que posso fazer pra melhorar o código.

```
def calculando_todos_acordes_e_diferencas():
    import pandas as pd
    import itertools                          
    anagrama=[]
    for i in range(1,13):
        anagrama.append(i)

    tst=[[[0],[0]]]
    df=pd.DataFrame(tst, columns=["notas","diferencas"])
    count_name=-1

    for qntd_notas in range(7):
        for i in itertools.product((anagrama), repeat=qntd_notas) :
            diferencas=[]
            count=-1
            for primeiro in i :
                count=count+1
        
        
                if i.index(primeiro) != len(i)-1 :
                    for segundo in i[count+1:]:
                        diferenca= segundo - primeiro
                        if diferenca < 0 :
                            diferenca=diferenca* -1
                        diferencas.append(diferenca)

          #  if len(df.index) == 100000 :
           #     count_name=count_name+1
            #    df=df.append({"notas":list(i),"diferencas":diferencas},ignore_index=True)
             #   df.to_csv("acordes e diferencas pt %s.csv" %(count_name), index=False)
              #  df=pd.DataFrame(tst, columns=["notas","diferencas"])

            df=df.append({"notas":list(i),"diferencas":diferencas},ignore_index=True)
    
    df.to_csv("acordes e diferencas TOTAL2.csv", index=False)
            #else:
            
     
calculando_todos_acordes_e_diferencas()
```

Comment: Estou um pouco confuso... Não seria `(12*11*10*9*8*7) + (12*11*10*9*8) + (12*11*10*9) + (12*11*10)` ? Não sou um profundo conhecedor de música, mas acredito que os acordes possuem no mínimo 3 notas. Sendo assim não teria `(12*11)` ou `(12)`. Quanto a redução do número em uma unidade, pensei: Após escolher uma nota para montar o acorde, você não pode escolhê-la de novo. Isso reduziria muito o tempo de processamento.